# How to redirect to next page on click of marker and displaying details about the marker?

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

I am using Leaflet to display map in my Hybrid app. In the map I have multiple markers. I want to redirect to next page when user click on the marker and also display details regarding the marker.
Below is my JSON data from where I am getting the lat and long for the marker.

**Below is my JSON data**

```
[{"store_id":"1","store_name":"Wall Mart","store_address":"Forum Mall, Kormangala","store_latitude":"12.929328","store_longitude":" 77.605117","store_phone":"9848484848"},
{"store_id":"2","store_name":"Lifestyle","store_address":"K R pooram","store_latitude":"12.961398","store_longitude":"77.553128","store_phone":"858585858"},
{"store_id":"3","store_name":"More","store_address":"Katriguppe","store_latitude":"12.989943","store_longitude":"77.689106","store_phone":"8796543210"}]
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```

**Controller**

```
var map = L.map('map', {
        center: new L.LatLng(12.96340871,77.59699345),
        zoom: 12,
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 6 
    });
    mapLink = 
        '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
        maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);

 $http.get('json.php').success(function(data) {
        // Loop through the 'locations' and place markers on the map
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        angular.forEach(data, function(location, key){
 // alert(location.store_name);
            var marker = L.marker([location.store_latitude, location.store_longitude]).addTo(map);

            });
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid this is too little information to give a useful answer. Could you add what code you are using and any particular problems you are running into?

Comment: [http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9150014](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9150014) I am following this example, to display multiple marker. Whenever user click on the marker, it should navigate to other page. @musically_ut

Answer (score 0):

You should use marker's [`click`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-click) event to bind some ridirect functionality. The routing manipulation can be achivied of `$location` service in angular:

```
angular.forEach(data, function(location, key){
  var marker = L.marker([location.store_latitude, location.store_longitude]).addTo(map);
  marker.click(function(e) {
    $location.path('/some_route');
  })    
});
```